# Using CSS variable for a CSS hover property in Angular directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have the following directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'd-btn', 
  host: {}
})

export class ButtonDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef){}
    @HostListener('mouseover')
    onMouseOver() {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.transition;
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "var(theme-color-1)";
    }
    
  
    @HostListener('mouseout')
    onMouseLeave() {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.transition;
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    }
}
```

If instead of "var(theme-color-1)" I write a color it adds the given color when the user hovers over the element. But I would like to give it a variable color, because I am working on different color themes. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain where you want to set the variable color? You mean per d-btn-component, right?

Comment: I have the following code in styles.css
:root{ 
  --theme-color-1:   rgb(54, 75, 139);
}
And when I change the color of a variable in any css-file to f.e.
background: var(--theme-color-1);
it gives it the given color.

Comment: this works easily in any css file or host of a directive I use, but not as a hover property of a directive

Comment: I think this is solvable using CSS the most easy way, so there is no need to manually set the styles. You think the answer I gave can be the solution for you? :)

Comment: Yes it worked! Perfect, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution should be pretty easy and is not an Angular problem. You can solve this easily by CSS:

```
button[d-btn] {
  transition: all .5s;
  background: transparent; 
}
button[d-btn]:hover {
  transition: all .5s;
  background: var(--theme-color-1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of small things. To use a css variable you need to have -- in front of it.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'button[d-btn]'
})
export class MyButtonDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef){}
  @HostListener('mouseover')
  onMouseOver() {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.transition;
      this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "var(--theme-color-1)";
  }
  

  @HostListener('mouseout')
  onMouseLeave() {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.transition;
      this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }
}
```

Also make sure the same color is defined, e.g in `style.css`.

```css
:root {
  --theme-color-1: red !important;
}
```

Apply the directive to a button like so.

```html
<button d-btn (click)="onClick($event)">Click Directive Button</button>
```

Here is an working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-1k8ycq?file=app%2Fbutton.directive.ts

Comment: These are also good notes to remember. But in this case, the CSS solution is probably the cleaner way, because there is no Angular overhead for the simple hover styling. :)